# How many lives have space agencies saved?

Tags: spacex, artificial-satellite, nasa, isro, space-agencies

Either the agencies themselves, lives saved by a satelitte launched by them, or how many people would have died if not for space services. How many lives have space agencies saved?

Comment: "how many people would have died if not for space services" Do you believe that this is answerable?

Comment: How do you propose to estimate the number of [Galveston hurricanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1900_Galveston_hurricane) that have been dodged due to the existence of weather satellites, and how do you propose to compare that to the number that would have been spotted by airplanes and/or ships?

Comment: I would guess millions, but the question is not objectively answerable.

Comment: Saved how? Space based observations help militaries avoid casualties while inflicting more on the other side, do we count these?

Comment: No, military satellittes don't exactly save lives, they change who dies @GdD

Comment: That's what I said @Starshipisgoforlaunch.

Comment: I was answering "do we count these" and explaining my reason @GdD

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based, my simple google search showed that in my answer below, though it could be closed for lack of prior research...

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 your answer is incredibly incomplete, omitting all the lives saved by space program developed technologies, remote sensing, GPS, communications over satcom, weather satellites, etc, etc, as well as all the world's other space agencies.

Comment: @OrganicMarble NASA spinoffs is "space program developed technologies", but I don't disagree, just showing that there are factual estimates out there

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 I didn't VTC; agree "opinion based" isn't exactly right, but there's not a "this question is, in practice, unaswerable" close reason.

Comment: SHADO saved all of humanity. Wait, what, UFO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_(TV_series)) wasn't a documentary???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [NASA Spinoffs presentation from 2012](https://spinoff.nasa.gov/Spinoff2012/pdf/Spinoff2012.pdf) an estimate is 444,000 for the period of 2000-2012 & 30,000 in 2012 alone:

[image: presentation slide 27]

As a specific example, [SARSAT systems](http://technosciences.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/datasheet_prisma_mcc.pdf) report over 48,000 lives saved since 1982. There are also [yearly breakdowns of people rescued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Cospas-Sarsat_Programme#Background).

Comment: And how does the 48,000 lives saved by SARSAT compare to the number that would have been saved by non-orbital monitoring of the 406 MHz distress-beacon frequency?

Comment: @Mark The 406 system is specifically designed for satellite use, [see the importance of doppler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_position-indicating_radiobeacon#Beacon_operation).